# A question about preventing duplicate user sessions in PHP

Tags: php, session

I have a session in PHP with 2 parameters: "auth" and "auth_id". Before I create a new session, I want to know if a session already exists with the "auth_id" that I am about to assign to this new session. Is there a way to do that in PHP? Thanks.

Comment: That depends on your session management system. But if you check if `$_SESSION['auth_id']` is set and has a value then it exists for that user.

Comment: Are you using any particular PHP framework? 
Typically PHP sessions are stored in the server in temp location, you can find the exact path using phpinfo(): 
You can change that path or store the sessions in a MySQL database to make things more managed and check within the sessions if you are able to find a session with those parameters.

Comment: But I don't want to check if $_SESSION['auth_id'] is set in general - I want to check if there exists a session that has a specific value as an "auth_id"

Comment: I use xampp and a modern version of PHP. There is a tmp folder here with files, I'm just not sure how to go about it.

Comment: @SabaKvesitadze So each session file will have a unique name that matches the session id for the user. The file will contain all the stored session variables. You should be able to find the variables there. So you can find if the auth id you have already exists in a session file.

Comment: The term "session" has a [very specific meaning in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php), but I suspect you're using it here to refer to a feature in your own custom code (even if you eventually use PHP sessions to build it). It would help a lot if you'd edit the question and explain in plain English what you're trying to accomplish ("I want to prevent users from logging in from different devices at once", or whatever), and maybe show some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Session is not supposed to be used as storage across different user session. Therefore there is not default way to search all existing sessions. The default session is stored in temp by hash as filenames. It would be extremely hard to scale up if you were to scan every session files for this.

However, you may use [session_set_save_handler()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) register your own [SessionHandlerInterface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php) implementation. And you may store all your session in a way you can easily access and search from.

For example,

```php
class MySessionHandler implements \SessionHandlerInterface {
  public __construct(private $myStorage) {
  }

  // Implements SessionHandlerInterface
  public close(): bool {
    $this->myStorage->close();
  }

  // Implements SessionHandlerInterface
  public destroy(string $id): bool{
    // Note: mock function here. Implement your own storage.
    $this->myStorage->deleteWhere('id', $id);
  }

  // Implements SessionHandlerInterface
  public gc(int $max_lifetime): int|false{
    // Note: mock function here. Implement your own storage.
    $this->myStorage->deleteWhere('created', time() - $max_lifetime, '<');
  }

  // Implements SessionHandlerInterface
  public open(string $path, string $name): bool{
    return true;
  }

  // Implements SessionHandlerInterface
  public read(string $id): string|false{
    // Note: mock function here. Implement your own storage.
    $this->myStorage->findWhere('id', $id);
  }

  // Implements SessionHandlerInterface
  public write(string $id, string $data): bool {
    // Note: mock function here. Implement your own storage.
    $raw = unserialize($data); // unserialize raw session data to get auth_id, if any
    return $this->myStorage->insert_or_create($id, $raw['auth_id'] ?? null, $data);
  }

  // ** Your own logic to check existing sessions for the auth id **
  public authIdExists($auth_id): bool{
    // Note: mock function here. Implement your own storage.
    $res = $this->myStorage->findWhere('auth_id', $auth_id);
    return !empty($res);
  }
}


// ....
$myStorage = new MyStorage();
$mySessionHandler = new MySessionHandler($myStorage);
session_set_save_handler($mySessionHandler);
session_start();

// ....

// Generate new auth id until it does not exists in the database.
do {
  $auth_id = generateAuthId();
} while ($mySessionHandler->authIdExists($auth_id));
$_SESSION['auth_id'] = $auth_id;
```

Comment: Doesn't this implementation have to scan every session file still?

Comment: @deepanshu223: The storage ($myStorage) is implemented by you. You may use MySQL or other way to quickly index / access the auth keys without accessing all the session files in the process. In fact, it is quite popular among PHP CMS to implement their own session with database.